# WPF: Style overrides property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a problem with WPF. When i'm creating a style, and then assign value to property of element, that uses this style, style overrides it.
Sample: I'm using a style for textblock. I need to set automation id to textblock. When i'm assigning a value to automationid property, due to style it disappears.

Here how it looks like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="SomeText"
                    Binding="{Binding SomeBinding}" 
                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource SomeTextBlockStyle}"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ColumnNameId"
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Possible solution is override style like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="SomeText"
                    Binding="{Binding SomeBinding}" 
                    IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style BasedOn={StaticResource SomeTextBlockStyle} TargetType={x:Type TextBlock}>
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="ColumnNameId"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

But that looks kinda dirty. Is there a way to make it cleaner?

UPD: SomeTextBlockStyle looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" x:Key="SomeTextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: How does `SomeTextBlockStyle` look like? You may also refer to [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list) for details

Comment: While the first XAML snippet sets the AutomationId attached property on the DataGridTextColumn, the second snippet (with the nested Style) sets the property on any TextBlock inside the visual tree of the DataGridTextColumn. Why do you expect the same result from both snippets?

Comment: @Clemens, oh i got it. Seems like there is no other way to set property to inner element but this?